# Android: Texture's gl states do not match with shader's

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

Getting an odd error validating my shaders on an android device. (It's an Asus eee Pad running Android 3.1)

> Texture's gl states do not match with shader's

Anybody know how to fix this error?

Here is the code generating the error:

```
GLES20.glValidateProgram(id);
GLES20.glGetProgramiv(id, GLES20.GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, ShaderStatus, 0);

if (ShaderStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
    String glerror = GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(id);
    throw new Error("ERROR TIME! failed to validate GLSL program");
}
```

Here is the vertex shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

attribute vec3 Position;
attribute vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform vec3 Location;
uniform float Angle;
uniform vec3 Scale;
uniform sampler2D Texture;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main(void) {
    mat3 RotationMatrix = mat3( cos( -Angle ), -sin( -Angle ),  0.0,
                                sin( -Angle ),  cos( -Angle ),  0.0,
                                0.0,           0.0,             1.0);

    gl_Position = Projection * vec4(RotationMatrix * (Position*Scale) + Location, 1.0);
    //vColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    vTexCoord = TexCoord;
}
```

Here is the fragment shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D Texture;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
uniform vec4 Color;

void main(void) {
    vec4 color = texture2D(Texture, vTexCoord) * Color;
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Comment: I get this with the Android demo code too, so i figure that it's something that i could ignore. Sure enough, after commenting out the code (and some other intense debugging), it worked.

Comment: What texture format is this? Tegra may require #pragma in the shader to inform the compiler that the texture is not in standard 8bit format. The same is done with blending. NVIDIA wasn't very strict in standards there.

Comment: I leave most of that to the library, so i hope this answer is what you were looking for: RGBA, and i think each channel was 8bit. I'll check on that and see if my assumptions are correct.

Comment: I would suggest creating a black square texture with RGBA8 format, GL_REPEAT wrap and mip-maps and try to reproduce the error. If it says this even for such basic format, then i'd say it's just a glitch that can be ignored.

Comment: And - oh yeah, the textures should be bound and ready to use at the time glValidateProgram() is called.

Comment: @leech I get the same error on Samsung Tablet 10.1 running Android 3.1. You said "I get this with the Android demo code too", can you tell me what exactly the demo was? It would probably help me bugfix this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My Tegra3 device would fail the glValidateProgram().
Like 'the swine' mentioned in the comment above, the texture not being bound will cause this.

So I fixed my validation error by only calling glValidateProgram() after the texture has been setup with **glActiveTexture**() and **glBindTexture**().

My device with Mali GPU never had problems with this though, so it could be a Tegra thing only.